# PHP Fatal Error: Call to undefined function password_verify()

Tags: php

I have `PHP 5.5.6` on my XAMPP and I didn't encounter the error. But after uploading my website to our testing environment the following error occurred:

```
PHP Fatal Error: Call to undefined function password_verify()
```

Our testing envt/server has PHP 5.5.9 (I checked it using command `php -v`)

I also checked the PHP manual and it says nothing to configure and nothing to install when using this functions. Any ideas what might be causing this issue?

Comment: @Tommy, It is a PHP built in function as of 5.5

Comment: i checked my php version using php -v and it says:

PHP 5.5.9 (cli) (built: blah blah)

Comment: CLI is not the same SAPI as webserver. Upload a file with phpinfo() to check what the webserver is running

Comment: I must say, as simple as this problem seems to be, it took me quite a while to realize this...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/function.password-verify.php) is built in since PHP 5.5.0 and it's most likely that your server doesn't run the latest PHP version. Be sure to double check the PHP version on your server either via [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/phpinfo) or [`phpversion()`](http://php.net/phpversion).

Please note that your CLI and `mod_php` (or php-fpm) versions might differ, executing `php -v` might give you a wrong version number. Create a PHP file and open it with your browser to be absolutely sure.

The reason for the differing versions of the CLI, `mod_php` and php-fpm are related to the packages which are offered by the operating system and what the actual administrator installed on the system. Personally I prefer to compile PHP on my own and be sure to get best performance but also the same version across the complete system.

Comment: i had checked it, using php -v and it says PHP 5.5.9

Comment: that's odd, php -v says its 5.5.9, and phpversion() says 5.3.3. thank you Fleshgrinder

Comment: It's because they are different installations. If it's your server simply update all PHP packages and your `mod_php` if you're using Apache httpd. If it's a hosting, well I guess you're out of luck.

Comment: Definitely another question and relies on your operating system, PHP via `mod_php` or php-fpm, do you have SSH access or is your hosting managed? Create a new question containing as many information about your server environment as possible and you'll get an answer right away.

Comment: not a hosting, but the team that is responsible with the server says its updated and they insist and says use the php -v :( sigh i guess i still got no luck

Comment: sorry i'm not pro on server thingy, im just a programmer, and i dont have access on the server, just a part/ folder

Comment: Well, show them that they're wrong and tell them to update the PHP web server SAPI.

Answer (score 4):

Replacement for PHP versions lower than 5.5

https://github.com/superandrew/phpPasswordHashingLib

Comment: moved server and didnt bother going to the effort of installing a non repo version of php...major oversight. This worked perfectly though, thank you