# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function password_verify() php 5.5.23

Tags: php

(this host is running cPanel and has a php version selector, it was using php 5.4 as default i changed it to 5.5 but still gives me error)

I made a script on localhost with php 5.5.9 now I uploaded it to my shared hosting and my login page is not loading and php error file says :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function password_verify() in ...
```

I know this function was added in PHP 5.5 and phpinfo on my shared host says: PHP Version 5.5.23

what should i do??

Comment: Same problem, seems solved http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21775970/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-password-verify

Comment: do they give you an option to restart the apache web server?  May need to do that...

Comment: @Aleksey Krivtsov how does that help?? i said that phpinfo is saying php 5.5.23

Comment: @Erik Flitman It's a shared host. not possible.

Comment: So, if you put `phpinfo()` just before your `password_verify` call, it tells you 5.5? Can you provide a link?

Comment: @vsg23434245 - Wait, they let you change the PHP version but don't let you restart the server? I think you're misunderstanding something and should speak to your host.